# Необходимо вызвать функцию, переданную ссылкой в качестве аргумента, внутрь метода класса JavaScript, конкретно React

Tags: javascript, ооп, reactjs

Я - новичок в ООП и в React. Хочу передать ссылку на стрелочную функцию через аргумент события onClick внутрь метода класса компонента Reac. Вот мой код:

```js
 class Notification extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = { alertClass: 'alert-info' };
}
 render() {
  switch (this.props.notification.type) {
    case 'success' :
   this.setState({ alertClass: 'alert-success' });
   break;
    case 'caution' :
   this.setState({ alertClass: 'alert-warning' });
   break;
    case 'error' :
   this.setState({ alertClass: 'alert-danger' });
   break;
  }
  if (this.props.notification.message === undefined || this.props.notification.message == '') return false;
  return (
   <div className={'alert ' + this.state.alertClass}>
    <p>{this.props.notification.message}</p>
    {this.props.children}
   </div>
    )
 }    
}

class Confirmation extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = { visibleConfirm: true };
 }
 clickButton(clickButtonFunc) {
  if (typeof clickButtonFunk === 'function') (clickButtonFunc)();
  this.setState({ visibleConfirm: false })
 }
 render() {
  let confirmBody = (
   <Notification notification={{ message: this.props.message, type: this.props.type}}>
    <div onClick={() => this.clickButton(this.props.accept)} className="btn btn-primary">Sure</div>
    <div onClick={() => this.clickButton(this.props.decline)} className="btn btn-danger">No Thanks</div>
   </Notification>
  );
  if (!this.state.visibleConfirm) confirmBody = ('');
  return (
   {confirmBody}
  )
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(
 <Confirmation 
  message="Hello" 
  type="message" 
  accept={ () => { console.log('accept') } }
  decline={ () => { console.log('decline') } }/>,
 document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Браузер даёт ошибку:

```js
react-dom.production.min.js:117 Invariant Violation: Minified React error #31; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=31&args[]=object%20with%20keys%20%7BconfirmBody%7D&args[]= for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings. 
    at pb (https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js:12:454)
    at n (https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js:13:221)
    at Ac (https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js:70:369)
    at https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js:80:190
    at N (https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js:90:3)
    at ce (https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js:98:226)
    at qg (https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js:97:440)
    at hi (https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js:104:285)
    at Qg (https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js:144:293)
    at Rg (https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js:145:168)
Bg @ react-dom.production.min.js:117
c.callback @ react-dom.production.min.js:126
Ag @ react-dom.production.min.js:116
zg @ react-dom.production.min.js:116
qi @ react-dom.production.min.js:131
ui @ react-dom.production.min.js:133
(anonymous) @ react-dom.production.min.js:158
unstable_runWithPriority @ react.production.min.js:27
Vc @ react-dom.production.min.js:158
Sc @ react-dom.production.min.js:158
Z @ react-dom.production.min.js:156
Kc @ react-dom.production.min.js:155
ya @ react-dom.production.min.js:153
bh @ react-dom.production.min.js:160
xe @ react-dom.production.min.js:160
nb.render @ react-dom.production.min.js:215
(anonymous) @ react-dom.production.min.js:164
$g @ react-dom.production.min.js:159
Wc @ react-dom.production.min.js:164
render @ react-dom.production.min.js:217
(anonymous) @ Inline Babel script:179
i @ babel.min.js:24
r @ babel.min.js:24
o @ babel.min.js:24
u @ babel.min.js:24
f @ babel.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ babel.min.js:1
react-dom.production.min.js:12 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Minified React error #31; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=31&args[]=object%20with%20keys%20%7BconfirmBody%7D&args[]= for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings. 
    at pb (https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js:12:454)
    at n (https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js:13:221)
    at Ac (https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js:70:369)
    at https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js:80:190
    at N (https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js:90:3)
    at ce (https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js:98:226)
    at qg (https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js:97:440)
    at hi (https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js:104:285)
    at Qg (https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js:144:293)
    at Rg (https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js:145:168)
pb @ react-dom.production.min.js:12
n @ react-dom.production.min.js:13
Ac @ react-dom.production.min.js:70
(anonymous) @ react-dom.production.min.js:80
N @ react-dom.production.min.js:90
ce @ react-dom.production.min.js:98
qg @ react-dom.production.min.js:97
hi @ react-dom.production.min.js:104
Qg @ react-dom.production.min.js:144
Rg @ react-dom.production.min.js:145
Sc @ react-dom.production.min.js:158
Z @ react-dom.production.min.js:156
Kc @ react-dom.production.min.js:155
ya @ react-dom.production.min.js:153
bh @ react-dom.production.min.js:160
xe @ react-dom.production.min.js:160
nb.render @ react-dom.production.min.js:215
(anonymous) @ react-dom.production.min.js:164
$g @ react-dom.production.min.js:159
Wc @ react-dom.production.min.js:164
render @ react-dom.production.min.js:217
(anonymous) @ Inline Babel script:179
i @ babel.min.js:24
r @ babel.min.js:24
o @ babel.min.js:24
u @ babel.min.js:24
f @ babel.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ babel.min.js:1
```

Помогите разобраться, в чем проблема. У меня уже мозг вскипел (((

Comment: проблема в строке: `return (
   {confirmBody}
  )` возможно сработало бы без фигурных скобок

Answer (score 0):

Все сработало, просто глаз замылился в ночи.
Исправил код вот так:

```
clickButton(clickButtonFunc) {
    if (typeof clickButtonFunc === 'function') clickButtonFunc();
    this.setState({ visibleConfirm: false });
}
render() {
    if (!this.state.visibleConfirm) return null;
    return (
        <Notification notification={{ message: this.props.message, type: this.props.type}}>
            <div onClick={() => this.clickButton(this.props.accept)} className="btn btn-primary">Sure</div>
            <div onClick={() => this.clickButton(this.props.decline)} className="btn btn-danger">No Thanks</div>
        </Notification>
    )
}
```

Так все работает. Всем спасибо за участие.